# How to select all 'checked' checkboxes pairs?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html-displayed question:

```
<div id="Question1"><span>1. </span>Which of the following have the same meaning?</div>
<div><input type="checkbox"  id="Question1Answer1Correct" /><input type="checkbox" id="Question1Answer1User"/><span id="Question1Answer1">String</span></div> 
<div><input type="checkbox"  id="Question1Answer2Correct" /><input type="checkbox" id="Question1Answer2User"/><span id="Question1Answer2">string</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="Question1Answer3Correct" /><input type="checkbox" id="Question1Answer3User"/><span id="Question1Answer3">Integer</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"  id="Question1Answer4Correct" /><input type="checkbox" id="Question1Answer4User"/><span id="Question1Answer4">int</span></div>
</div>
```

Now I need to retrieve all answers which their "Correct" and "User" checkboxes are checked - and mark them as correct, all those whose "Correct" and "User" checkboxes are unchecked - and also mark them as correct, and mark all other answers as incorrect.

I was starting to do that like so:

```
$('#checkAnswers').click(function(){            
    $.each($("input[id^='Question1Answer1']"),function(){ 

    if ($("#Question1Answer1Correct").attr('checked') && $("#Question1Answer1User").attr('checked') )
{
    $('#Question1Answer1').css('color','#00AB32'); //that's green for correct
}   
});
```

But it seems too hard for me to generalize that.
Question is - how do I make this code work for all answers (you can assume of course  all answers have the same naming scheme).

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve this by using `.filter()`

```
$('#checkAnswers').click(function() {
    $("span").css("color", "");
    $("div > :checkbox").parent().filter(function() {
        return $(this).find(":checked").length == 2 || $(this).find(":checked").length == 0;
    }).find("span").css('color', '#00AB32');
});
```

Target only checkboxes that are in the div, use `.parent()` and then `.filter()` to only find the elements that have 0 checks or both checked and simply color the `<span/>`.

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/CNbav/2/)**

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. Secondly I want to tell you that this seems like one of the most awesome snippets of code I've ever seen.